# Check if the words in a column matches the words in a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, append, string-matching

[data snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rO6gQ.png)

Hi all,
I am new to python programming. I have data with a set of columns as shown in the picture. For each of the occupation there are relevant hard skills but it is actually a combination of both hard skills and technology skills. My aim is to create a new column which classifies each of the skill into hard or tech so that it would be easier for me to filter it later. I have created a dictionary of tech skills.  I wanted to check if there is match between the dictionary words and hard skills column words. Can you please help me with the code? The dictionary words are as follows:

**dict = {tech_skills:['Android (Operating System)','Apple IOS','Apple IPhone','Computer Keyboards','Computer Terminals','Corel Wordperfect Office', 'FaceTime','Gmail','Google Apps','Google Docs','Google Voice','Google+','Microsoft Excel', 'Microsoft Internet Explorer','Microsoft Office','Microsoft Outlook','Microsoft PowerPoint', 'Microsoft Visio','Microsoft Windows','Microsoft Windows NT','Microsoft Windows XP','Microsoft Word', 'Mobile Devices','Skype','Tableau (Business Intelligence Software)']}**

Comment: What have you tried doing so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
# Copy hard_skills_name onto a new column
df['matched'] = df['hard_skills_name']

# replace with 1 if matched with the techskills
df['matched'].replace(dict['tech_skills'],1,inplace=True)

# replace non-matched with 0
df['matched'][df['matched'] != 1] = 0
```

Then you can check the data frame which matched:

```
print(df[df['matched']=1])
```